# activity diagram - connector to group of activities

Tags: uml

When one activity leads on to a number of other activities (e.g. 100), is there a way to illustrate this process flow without drawing a connector to each next activity?

I.e. is there a grouping container I can put a 100 activities in, and then draw a connector from the previous activity to the container - to imply that the workflow connects to each of the 100 next activities grouped in the container?

Comment: What should that mean? An activity that triggers a 100? Sounds like you want to document chaos.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, your activity is **triggering** other 100. Of course, you are not calling them directly, but you are changing some state that would trigger these 100 activities.

So, change some state on that number one diagram. And on all other 100 diagrams (if you create them) launch the activity by that state. You won't see these 100 activities on the first activity diagram, of course.

The solution to launch these 100 from the state on the state diagram would be bad because of that chaos of 100 references.